# Можно ли на Stack Overflow создать два аккаунта на одну почту?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника, почта

Можно ли на Stack Overflow создать два аккаунта на одну электронную почту?

Comment: Наверное, можно попробовать добавить суффикс к юзернейму через плюсик, типа `username+suffix@mail.com`, это вроде поддерживается многими почтовиками, а сайты о такой фиче часто забывают. Однако вы, вероятно, получите люлей от модераторов

Comment: а зачем второй аккаунт?

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать отдельно аккаунт по python и отдельно по всему остальному

Comment: Аккаунт делается не для языка/темы, а для человека

Comment: А-а-а! Я этого не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: С одного аккаунта можно отвечать на всё - Вам же лучше, репутации больше)

Comment: Ну да. Я это уже понял)

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8, хотите много баллов?

Answer (score 3):

При попытке регистрации на тот же адрес, для которого уже имеется аккаунт, выводится следующее окно:

> [image: Восстановление]

Т.о. система не позволяет создать второй аккаунт на одном и том же адресе электронной почты.

Comment: Глупый вопрос: некоторые почтовые сервисы разрешают использовать различные почтовые адреса на одном ящике (например vasy@yandex.ru, vasya@yandex.com и, кажется, vasya@ya.ru). В данном случае система же распознаёт их как разные ящики, да? пруф на доп-адреса https://yandex.ru/support/mail/web/preferences/about-sender/additional-addresses.html

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski вряд ли в StackOverflow знают о всех возможных синонимах всех возможных почтовых сервисов. Так что, да, такая ситуация будет возможна.